# The median and angle bisector from a vertex being distinct

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

I have an argument here for the proposition that the median and the angle bisector from an acute angle in a right triangle are distinct line segments. I would appreciate comments on it.  (I can include a diagram that may be compiled on LaTeX.)

**Proposition**

```
$\triangle{ABC}$ is a right triangle with its right angle at $A$. The median and the angle bisector from either $B$ or $C$ are distinct line segments.
```

**Demonstration**

$P$ is any point on the leg $\overline{AB}$, and $\theta = {\mathrm{m}}\angle{CPB}$. According to the Pythagorean Theorem, $\bigl\vert \overline{BC} \bigr\vert > \bigl\vert \overline{CP} \bigr\vert$. Since $\sin\theta \leq 1$,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\sin\theta}{\overline{BC}} < \frac{1}{\overline{CP}} .
\end{equation*}
If $\overline{CP}$ were both the median and the angle bisector of the given triangle from $C$, and if ${\mathrm{m}}\angle{ACP} = \phi = {\mathrm{m}}\angle{PCB}$, according to the Law of Sines,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{\overline{CP}} = \frac{\sin\phi}{\overline{AP}} = \frac{\sin\phi}{\overline{BP}} = \frac{\sin\theta}{\overline{BC}} . 
\end{equation*}
This is a contradiction.

Comment: There is a tag for proof verification and you might want to add it.

Comment: In your last part of the first line and in your last equality of the second last line, the $\sin(\phi)$ probably should be $\sin(\theta)$ and other than that I think the proof is good.

Comment: @cr001  I made the edit that you suggested - replaced "\phi" with "\theta".  Thanks.

Comment: @cr001  I added the tag that you suggested.  I did not know about this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a contradiction which is slightly simpler.

[image]

Suppose that the said median and the angle bisector are not distinct. Then, the right angled triangle will have lengths as shown.

By angle bisector theorem, $\dfrac {a}{x} = \dfrac {b}{x}$. Consequently, a = b. This is a contradiction because the hypotenuse should be the longest in a right angled triangle.

Comment: I am writing a chapter for a course in Geometry, and citing the Angle-Bisector Theorem would be out of order.  I do have the Law of Sines (and the Law of Cosines) preceding this proposition.  I am looking for an elementary demonstration for this proposition.  Do you agree that the demonstration that I provided is correct?  By the way, I do have code in `TikZ` that I could include.  Do you think that I should include it? It would make my post look really messy.

Comment: I should complement you on your demonstration. Very Nice!

Comment: @user74973 It's sad & also funny that the angle bisector theorem is being excluded in many schools/ institutes. First of all, the proof of it is not that difficult to derive. Secondly, it is very powerful in certain occasions. Without it, one might have to go thro' many extra steps before the desired can be attained. Regarding your book, I suggest introducing the theorem 'indirectly' as:- 1) After similar triangles being taught, 2) introduce the angle bisector environment with the needed construction included. 3) Ask the readers to prove the needed ratio. 4) Solve problems requiring the ratio.

Comment: The books to which I refer to it as "The Triangle-Bisector Theorem." I think it is ridiculous that it is not taught.  The demonstration of it is a clever use of auxiliary lines to verify geometric propositions.  Except for using it to verify other important propositions, I haven't seen any nice examples using it.  (By the way, I would describe what I am doing as writing several chapters on various topics in geometry.  It is to be used for a supplement for a college course in geometry - a course in which students learn to prove statements.)

Comment: Having said that, do you agree that the argument I provided is lucid?

Comment: @user74973 1) There is typo. The very last $\phi$ should be a $\theta$. 2) If your target is junior levels, some more details should be included like naming the triangle in target before applying the sine law. 3) Combining the results of two applications of sine laws into one may cause confusion. 4) Further explanation on why the first two inequalities induce the third may be needed.

Comment: Thanks for alerting me to the typographical error.  I edited my post to avoid unnecessary confusion to others who will read it.

Comment: The class is supposed to be for students who want to study math.  They should know that if you have two quotients and the numerator of the first quotient is less than the numerator of the second quotient, and the denominator of the first quotient is more than the denominator of the second quotient, the first quotient is less than the second quotient.

Comment: I understand that without naming the triangles before using the Law of Sines, the students will have to exert some effort to determine how I am applying the Law of Sines. Hmmm. To include all that would make a simple argument look messy. I am going to decide in favor of brevity.

Comment: Again, thanks for your assistance.